# How to find all Shared Step references for a given ITestCase object in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-sdk

Given that I have a `ITestCase` object obtained like so

```
ITestCase tc = project.TestCases.Find(2034);
```

Where `project` is an object of type `ITestManagementTeamProject` obtained by

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsLocation));
ITestManagementService testService = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
return testService.GetTeamProject(projectName);
```

How do I get all the shared step references(don't even know if there was one in the first place) for that particular test case, considering that I don't have any prior state knowledge about that test case.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **[ISharedStepReference Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.isharedstepreference(v=vs.120).aspx)** to call a shared step from a test case. You just need to use ***FindSharedStep*** method return the shared step definition from the server. A sample code for your reference:

```
public ISharedStep tstSharedStep { get; private set; }

public ISharedStepReference tstSharedStepRef { get; private set; }

    foreach (ITestAction tstAction in tstCase.Actions)
            {
                tstSharedStep = null; 
                tstSharedStepRef = tstAction as ISharedStepReference;
                    if (tstSharedStepRef != null)
                    {
                        tstSharedStep = tstSharedStepRef.FindSharedStep();
                        foreach (ITestAction tstSharedAction in tstSharedStep.Actions)
                        {
                            ITestStep tstSharedTestStep = tstSharedAction as ITestStep;
                            resultData.Step = Regex.Replace(tstSharedTestStep.Title, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
                            resultData.ExpectedResult = Regex.Replace(tstSharedTestStep.ExpectedResult, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();

                        }
                    }
                    else {
                     // regular step action
                    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Just one last question, if I needed to remove the shared step reference, does removing all action for that test case does that job?

Comment: @SohamDasgupta  Yes, you could use `TestCase.Actions.Remove(xx)` to this. Here is a related thread with some code sample: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/426b46f0-6a73-4f09-bc7a-83243e803c57/problem-using-the-itestcaseitestcollectionremove-function?forum=vsmantest